# How to show pagination in get_posts function?

Tags: wordpress

In My current project I am using `get_posts` and would want to show pagination, but I am unable to achieve that. Someone suggested to use `WP_Query` but I don't want to change my code now, does anyone know how to show pagination in the `get_posts` function?

```
function law_cp_gallery_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
        $result = shortcode_atts( array(
            'width' => '1/2',
            'el_position' => '',
            'element_title' => '',
            'element_caption' => '',
            'show_title' => '',
            'num_posts' => '',
            'read_more' => '',
            'excerpt' => '',
            'num_characters' => '',
            'category_name' => '',
            'display_styles' => 'blog_gallery',
            'post_columns' => '',
            'thumbnail_position' => '',
            'menu_filter' => '',
            'show_post_title' => '',
            'show_description' => '',
            'pretty_photo' => ''
        ), $atts );

        extract( $result );
        global $wpdb,$post;
        $args = array();
        $stack = array();
        $stack_cat_all = array();
        $category_id = 0;

        if($category_name != 'All' && !empty($category_name)){
            $term = get_term_by('name', $category_name, 'category');
            $category_id = $term->term_id;

            $stack_cat_all = array('tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'terms' => $category_id,
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                )
            ),
            );
        }
        //Setting posts count
        if($num_posts == ""){
            $num_posts = 8;
        } else {
            $num_posts = $num_posts;
        }

        if($num_characters == ""){
            $num_characters = 120;
        } else {
            $num_characters = $num_characters;
        }

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => $num_posts,
        );
        $push_args = array_slice($args, 0, 2, true) + $stack + $stack_cat_all + array_slice($args, 2, count($args) - 1, true) ;

        query_posts($push_args);
        if($show_title == 'yes'){
            $output = '<div class="section-title">';
            $output .= '<h3>'.$element_title.'</h3>';
            $output .= '<small>'.$element_caption.'</small>';
            $output .= '</div>';
        }
        if($menu_filter != 'hide'){
            $output .= '<div class="tnit-gallery-filter"><div class="row"><div id="filters" class="button-group"><button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">All</button>';
            //$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
            $args = array(
                'orderby'           => 'name',
                'order'             => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'        => false,
                'exclude'           => array(),
                'exclude_tree'      => array(),
                'include'           => array(),
                'number'            => '',
                'fields'            => 'all',
                'slug'              => '',
                'parent'            => '',
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'child_of'          => 0,
                'childless'         => false,
                'get'               => '',
                'name__like'        => '',
                'description__like' => '',
                'pad_counts'        => false,
                'offset'            => '',
                'search'            => '',
                'cache_domain'      => 'core'
            );
            $terms = get_terms('portfolio_category', $args);
            foreach($terms as $term) {
                $output .= '<button class="button" data-filter="'.'.'.$links = str_replace(" ", "-", $term->name) .'">' . $term->name .'</button>';
            }
            $output .= '</div></div></div>';
        }
        $output .= '<div class="isotope row">';
        if($post_columns == ''){
            $post_cols = "col-md-12";
        } else if($post_columns == 'two_column') {
            $post_cols = "col-md-6";
        } else if($post_columns == 'three_column') {
            $post_cols = "col-md-4";
        } else if($post_columns == 'four_column') {
            $post_cols = "col-md-3";
        }
        $loop = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => $num_posts, 'post_status' => 'publish'));
        if ( !empty($loop) ) {

            foreach($loop as $lop) { setup_postdata( $post );
                $terms = get_the_terms( $lop->ID, 'portfolio_category' );
                $links = array();
                if (is_array($terms) || is_object($terms)) {
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        $links[] = $term->name;
                    }
                }
                $links = str_replace(' ', '-', $links);
                $tax = join( " ", $links );
                //$feat_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($lop->ID, array(180,180));
                $output .= '<div class="element-item '. $tax. ' '.$post_cols.'" data-category="transition">';

                /*if($custom_url == ''){
                    $custom_url = $lop->guid;
                } else {
                    $custom_url = $custom_url;
                }*/
                if($thumbnail_position != 'below_title'){
                    if($pretty_photo != 'no') {
                        $output .= '<a href="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)) . '" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)) . '"></a>';
                    } else {
                        $output .= '<a href="' .$lop->guid . '"><img src="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)) . '"></a>';
                    }
                }
                if($show_post_title != 'no') {
                    $output .= '<h3><a href="' . $lop->guid . '">' . $lop->post_title . '</a></h3>';
                }
                if($show_description != 'no') {
                    $output .= '<p>' . $content = substr($lop->post_content, 0, $num_characters) . '</p>';
                }
                if($thumbnail_position == 'below_title') {
                    if($pretty_photo != 'no') {
                        $output .= '<a href="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)) . '" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)) . '"></a>';
                    } else {
                        $output .= '<a href="' . $lop->guid . '"><img src="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)) . '"></a>';
                    }
                }
                /*if($excerpt != '') {
                    $excerpt = $excerpt;
                } else {
                    $excerpt = '...';
                }*/
                if($read_more != '') {
                    $read_more = $read_more;
                } else {
                    $read_more = 'Read More';
                }
                if(($show_post_title != 'no') && ($show_description != 'no') ) {
                    $output .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . $read_more . '</a>';
                }
                $output .= '</div>';
            }
        }

        $output .= '</div>';

        //$output .= '</div>';
        //$output .= '</div>';
        wp_reset_query();
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $output;
    }
```

Its huge code and that's why I was unable to make it in WP_Query working :(

Comment: You should use `WP_Query` and will likely need to. `get_posts` doesn't return the number of found rows which is usually required for pagination. `get_posts` actually uses `WP_Query` to return it's results but has the found rows parameter turned off.  If you would like to show your current code I would be happy to help you convert it from `get_posts` to using `WP_Query`. There really isn't much of a difference and you can use the same arguments.

Comment: You can page `get_posts`, but it requires big unnecessary overhead as you need to run xtra db queries which makes this expensive

Comment: ok I am providing all my code in my question and will need that solution in WP_Query if any one can ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your query argument for example $args:

```
$args = array( 
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'post_type' => 'post',
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
   );
```

And then after loop put this:

```
if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
    wp_pagenavi();
}
```

Comment: Won't work. Paging functions needs to know how many pages there are

Comment: then can we get total number of pages by our own, like getting all posts count, then dividing by per page posts count and it will give us total number of posts ... am I RIGHT ? Can then we use pagination etc